# Codeigniter, atualizar valor com "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Boas, quero fazer update a uma tabela onde numa das variaveis quero inserir o valor "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Numa situação normal bastava enviar o valor como uma string e o sql iria interpreta-lo e traduzi-lo para a data atual.

A questão é que não o está a fazer e eu não percebo o porquê.

O meu código é o seguinte e estou a usar a framework CodeIgniter.

```
public function resetlogin(){
        $this->db->set('ulogin', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
        $this->db->set('tentativa1', 0);
        $this->db->set('tentativa2', 0);
        $this->db->where('codigo',18990);
        $this->db->update('usuario');

    }
```

Todos os restantes valores são atualizados normalmente.

Alguem consegue identificar o problema?

Comment: você ja tentou deixar a estrutura tabela para fazer essa inserção automática ? onde você define no `DB` que a coluna `ulogin`  e do tipo `timestamp`. Ou você mesmo que inserir ?

Comment: o que é inserido no campo `ulogin` quando esse código é executado?

Comment: 0000-00-00 00:00

Comment: Ainda não tentei fazer a inserção automática, amanhã vou tentar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa desativar o `escape` para utilizar funções do MYSQL, senão o CodeIgniter vai fazer:

```
UPDATE usuario SET ulogin = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

O terceiro parametro do método `set` é booleano (TRUE por padrão) para ativar ou desativar o *escape*

```
$this->db->set('ulogin', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou:

```
$this->db->set('ulogin', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', FALSE);
```

Ou

```
$this->db->set('ulogin', 'NOW()', FALSE);
```